# macbook pro only pulls private ip

Tags: mac, ip

I'm on a mid 2011 mbp and I've now connected to two different routers and two different cable modems via Ethernet. I've tried manually assigning the IP addresses for the routers and no matter what I do. The Ethernet does not work. It detects the connection but if I leave it on dhcp it always pulls a private IP. I know it has inet access. Any ideas? Trying to avoid a reinstall.

Comment: The modem pulls the public IP assigned by the ISP generally and then assigns one private IP from its own DHCP server to the device connected to the LAN port. What documentation from your ISP tells you any differently? As it would be abnormal if this works as you explained.

Comment: I know it's different because another computer plugged in still pulls an IP. and it only doesn't pull on Ethernet.

Comment: I think your terminology must be off THEN, because as it stands the question doesn't make sense. A　private IP has to do with network classes... Are you getting a specific IP address on your network? 169.x.x.x for example?

Comment: Yes. Pulling a 169.x.x.x. My question makes perfect sense. Let's say I leave it on DHCP and plug into a router with confirmed internet access (where one computer is already wired and others are wireless, so I know DHCP works). The mac in question will STILL only pull a private IP.

Comment: 169.x.x.x is not a typical private IP. It is a reserved range for link-local addresses (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address).

Comment: Ah shoot. My bad. Either way, I'm at a loss as to how to correct this.

Comment: Well, you'll want to start with the network details you're on. Ensure that you have the subnet mask and gateway properly configured when setting a manual connection. If you have that set right, see if you can ping the default gateway. It sounds like the Mac is setting that IP because it can't contact the DHCP server. You could take a pcap on that iface and see if there is any response to ARP requests. If you see no return traffic (ARP, ICMP, etc) then try replacing the cable or moving to another switch port.

Comment: It's not the network config considering this happens on EVERY network I hop onto via Ethernet. Plus, WIFI works just fine. IT's JUST ethernet. IT's something to to with the Mac.

Comment: You might have a bad NIC.

Comment: That's what I was fearing. Though it detects that it's connected. That's the odd part. Typically they don't detect at all.

Comment: Are you using the same patch cable, or different cables on the various networks you've tried?

Comment: Turned out to be an issue with DHCP. NIC tested fine.